# Available function for deletion of character from certain positions of a string

Tags: r

I am looking for a function which performs delete operation on a string based on the position.

For example, given string is like that

```
string1 <- "hello stackoverflow"
```

Suppose, I want to delete 4th,10th and 18th positions.

**Preferred Output**

```
"helo stakoverflw"
```

I am not sure about the existence of such function.

Comment: Hello everyone. I am very much interested about the pre-existing function. I can also write one-liner. Maybe **I am looking for an one-liner.** made confusion here. Sorry for that.

Comment: Rather than pre-existing function, could you write your own function that does what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a preexisting function. R doesn't store strings as vectors of single-character elements like python does.

Comment: technically a one-liner `\`regmatches<-\`(string1, gregexpr(paste0(sprintf('(?<=^.{%s}).', c(4,10,18) - 1), collapse = '|'), string1, perl = TRUE), value = '')`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
string1 <- "hello stackoverflow"
paste((strsplit(string1, "")[[1]])[-c(4,10,18)],collapse="")
[1] "helo stakoverflw"
```

I used `strsplit` to split the string into a vector of characters, and then pasted only the desired characters back together into a string.

You could also write a function that does this:

```
delChar <- function(x,eliminate){
  paste((strsplit(x,"")[[1]])[-eliminate],collapse = "")
}

delChar(string1,c(4,10,18))
[1] "helo stakoverflw"
```

Comment: With this approach it might be more convenient to use: `paste((strsplit(string1, "")[[1]])[-c(4,10,18)],sep="",collapse="")` so you specify the characters you want to remove not the ones you want to keep.

Comment: Haha literally changed that right when your comment was posted.  Good point with `-c()` rather than `c(-3)`.

Comment: `paste((strsplit(string1, "")[[1]])[c(-4,-10,-18)],collapse="")` should be good enough, you don't need to specify both `sep` and `collapse`.